# Can't reach drawer headerView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

What might be the reason that i am not able to reach HeaderView from navigationView?
I am using android studio project with drawer template, in `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` in `onCreate` method i want to update navigation header(`nav_header_main`)
In `onCreate` I call the following method:

```
private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
        TextView tvUserName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);

        if (signedIn) {
                tvUserName.setText(acc.getDisplayName());
            }

        } else {
                tvUserName.setText("-");
            }
        }
    }
```

navigationView seems to have all the needed values, but HeaderView is null
(`View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);` returns null)
it seems that it is not initialized at this point or something.
when i call the same method from `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` everything is ok, so i think that the problem is that i am calling it before initialization?
any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason changing

```
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
```

to

```
 View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

did the trick